# Powermock driven tests run just fine via maven but don't run in intellij

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, powermock

I have a very large project where and at some point developers started noticing that if they try to run/debug a PowerMock driven test in intellij- they get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/core/transformers/impl/MainMockTransformer
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassTransformer.<clinit>(PowerMockClassTransformer.java:41)
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.<clinit>(PowerMockAgent.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

We are using the powermockagent, and a unit test usually looks like this:

```
@PrepareForTest({Bla.class})
public class BlaTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    static {
        PowerMockAgent.initializeIfNeeded();
    }

    @Test public void test() { ... }
 }
```

interestingly enough, if I *disable* dynamic.path, the issue goes away but I consider it a workaround, not a solution since I need the dynamic.path in other scenarios.

Powermock version: 1.6.3 | Junit version: 4.11 | Intellij version: 2016.3

I'll appreciate any insights.

Comment: *"`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`"*  The error is obvious caused by a configuration problem in IntelliJ concerning the classpath. You may be missing a runtime dependency of PowerMock.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, running via maven works, turning off dynamic classpath works. This is not one of those silly "gosh I forgot a dependency" cases I am afraid.

Comment: @ Vitaliy: *"This is not one of those silly "gosh I forgot a dependency" cases"* but this is what the stacktrace tells us. Did you import the project "as maven project" (what ever IntelliJ calls that) and did you correctly sync the IntelliJ project   with the maven configuration? In *eclipse* parent projects don't need to be imported into the workspace, Does IntelliJ behave the same?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, yes I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out [this is a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165929)
The workaround was to set property idea.dynamic.classpath.jar in IDEA_CONFIG/options/options.xml to true.

Note that it was set to false in the first place due to [another know issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154486#comment=27-1469813).

This is pretty cumbersome but this is the best there is for now (March 2017).

Comment: Where can i find this xml?

Comment: @Teja, I describe it in the answer above.

Comment: @Vitaliy Well now we are in 2020 and I currently have -> 

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 (Community Edition) Build #IC-193.6911.18, built on March 17, 2020 Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43 x86_64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.15.4

-> And I dont see any of the files mentioned in the links you've provided. Can you help me with any latest updates to resolve this.

Comment: @NitinRamac see my answer

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by changing the test configuration setup `shorten command line`.
I changed it from `classpath file` to `JAR manifest`.
It's located in `Run -> Edit Configurations`. Just make sure you change the correct configuration for the test you are running.

[image]

Comment: Don't see this shorten command line option?

Comment: Perhaps it was moved to some other place in new versions of IntelliJ